# Python: converting strings for use with ctypes.c_void_p()

Tags: python, dll, types, ctypes

given a string:

```
msg="hello world"
```

**How can I define this as a `ctypes.c_void_p()` data type?**

the following code yields a "cannot be converted to pointer" exception:

```
data=ctypes.c_void_p(msg)
```

`data` is required to be a `void*` type in C, because it is being passed to a DLL.

I'm assuming there is a way to pack/unpack the string using the `struct` package, but unfortunately I am very unfamiliar with this process.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this?  Using `ctypes.cast`?

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> p1= ctypes.c_char_p("hi mom")
>>> ctypes.cast( p1, ctypes.c_void_p )
c_void_p(11133300)
```