# Using ctypes.c_void_p as an input to glTexImage2D?

Tags: python, opengl, ctypes, pyopengl

I'm using a 3rd party DLL to load in some raw image data, and I want to use this raw image data as a texture in openGL.  However, the c function returns a void*, and I need to somehow convert this so it will work as the "pixels" parameter to glTexImage2D.  Right now my code looks like something this:

```
data = c_void_p(vdll.vlImageGetData()) 
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGB8, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data )
```

However, I get a TypeError complaining that data 'cannot be converted to pointer'.  Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Edit:  Figured it out.  Basically what I do is this:

```
data = create_string_buffer( BUFFER_SIZE )
data = dll.vlImageGetData()
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGB8, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data )
```

Answer (score 1):

An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318067/python-converting-strings-for-use-with-ctypes-cvoidp/318140#318140) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318067/python-converting-strings-for-use-with-ctypes-cvoidp) suggested to use `ctypes.cast()`.

Comment: This doesn't work because the pyopenGL expects the pixels param to be a raw string.  I can't use c_char_p because that expects a null-terminated string.  I need a way to convert that void pointer into a raw python string.

Comment: Have you already seen http://osdir.com/ml/python.ctypes/2004-12/msg00002.html ? If yes and it didn't help, you should provide a small stand-alone skript that we can execute locally.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help.  There is a similar issue on use of c_void_p as a return type.  I instead have to return c_longlong AND do some hokey tricks:

if I am returning a pointer c_types obejct, I have to cast its reference to a POINTER to c_longlong to get the integer value to return.  (NOTE that CFUNCTYPE will not accept POINTER(x) types as a return type):

retvalp = cast( byref(retval), POINTER(c_longlong)) #retval is what I WANT to return
return retvalp.contents.value