# Python swig - create swig wrapped instance from ctypes pointer

Tags: python, swig

I have C++ code with a class wrapped with swig. I cannot modify the code or the wrapping. 
In python, I have, using ctypes, a pointer to an instance of said C++ class. 
How can I create a swig wrapper around this pointer?

I know that swig objects hold a 'this' attribute which internally points to the wrapped object, but I couldn't find a way to set it to the pointer that I have on hand.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do this, but it's rather a lot of work and it would be much simpler to fix the underlying problem of making either the ctypes or the SWIG interface complete and usable than force interchangeability. (It's also worth noting that it's easier to create a ctypes object from a SWIG one than it is to do what you're trying to do, which is to create a SWIG object from a ctypes one).

To illustrate this I've created the following header file that we'll wrap with SWIG:

```cpp
struct Foo {
  double d;
  char msg[20];
};
```

Then I wrapped it with the following interface:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

// Prove I'm not cheating here - we can't even instantiate this class
%nodefaultctor;

%include "test.h"
```

I also added a test function for us to call from ctypes, that isn't SWIG wrapped:

```cpp
#include "test.h"

// This function returns a Foo, but is only accessible to ctypes
extern "C" Foo *fun1() {
    static Foo f = { 1.234, "Hello" };
    return &f;
}
```

Your guess about this `this` attribute of SWIG wrapped classes is a good starting point, but it's not as simple as just changing that - the type of the object you slot in has to match what SWIG expects. It's more than just a pointer represented as an int:

```py
repr(test.Foo().this) # You'll need to drop the nodefaultctor directive to see this
"<Swig Object of type 'Foo *' at 0x7f621197d1e0>"
```

If we inspect the source code that SWIG generates we can see that there is a function which takes a pointer, some type information and creates these objects for us:

```cpp
SWIGRUNTIME PyObject *
SwigPyObject_New(void *ptr, swig_type_info *ty, int own);
```

Let's ignore the fact that `SWIGRUNTIME` is defined as `static` by default for now, to get us started experimenting with this runtime we can redefine it to `extern`. Later we'll look at workarounds for when we can't do that.

So our goal is to take the output of the "ctypes only" function and pass it, via more ctypes calls into `SwigPyObject_New` to create something we can swap around for with the this attribute of our SWIG module.

In order to call that we'd normally call `SWIG_TypeQuery` to lookup the correct `swig_type_info` to use. However this is actually a macro, which expands to pass in some static variables that are always static. So instead we'll be using this function:

```cpp
SWIGRUNTIME swig_type_info *
SWIG_Python_TypeQuery(const char *type)
```

(with the same `SWIGRUNTIME` proviso).

At this point we've got enough that we could swap the this attribute of a surrogate object and be done if we were able to construct donors. (Although that would leak). There are two ways we can make this nicer:

1. Monkey patch `__init__` inside `test.Foo` to work. This is best if you really have `%nodefaultctor` inside the SWIG interface you don't want to recompile:

   ```py
   def patched_init(self, ptr):
       self.this = ptr
   test.Foo.__init__ = patched_init
   ```
2. Create a new class that only has an `__init__` which sets the `this` attribute before modifying the `__class__` attribute and use that instead:

   ```py
   class FooCtypesSwigInterop(object):
       def __init__(self, ptr):
           self.this = ptr
           self.__class__ = test.Foo
   ```

   this option makes most sense when you don't want to break `test.Foo`'s existing `__init__` implementation.

With that said we can now achieve our initial goal with something like this:

```py
import ctypes
import test

# This *must* happen after the import of the real SWIG module
# 0x4 is RTLD_NOLOAD which ensures that we get the same handle as the Python 
# import did, even if it was loaded with RTLD_LOCAL as Python is prone to.
swig_module = ctypes.PyDLL('./_test.so',ctypes.RTLD_LOCAL|0x4)
# Note that we used PyDLL instead of CDLL because we need to retain the GIL

# Setup SWIG_Python_TypeQuery to have the right argument/return types
# (Using void* as a substitute for swig_type_info*)
SWIG_Python_TypeQuery = swig_module.SWIG_Python_TypeQuery
SWIG_Python_TypeQuery.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
SWIG_Python_TypeQuery.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

# Likewise SwigPyObject_New, using ctypes.py_object though for return
SwigPyObject_New = swig_module.SwigPyObject_New
SwigPyObject_New.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_int]
SwigPyObject_New.restype = ctypes.py_object

# Actually do the type query for the type our ctypes function returns:
SWIGTYPE_p_Foo = SWIG_Python_TypeQuery('Foo*')
print(hex(SWIGTYPE_p_Foo))

# Now the ctypes function itself that returns the type we want SWIG managed
fun1 = swig_module.fun1
fun1.argtypes = []
fun1.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

# Make the actual ctypes call we care about here
result = fun1()
print(hex(result))

# And then create a SwigPyObject for it from the void* return type
# Note that 0 means not owned by SWIG
sresult = SwigPyObject_New(result, SWIGTYPE_p_Foo, 0)
print(repr(sresult))

# This is how we jimmy it back into the this attribute of a SWIG type
class FooCtypesSwigInterop(object):
    def __init__(self, ptr):
        self.this = ptr
        self.__class__ = test.Foo

c = FooCtypesSwigInterop(sresult)

# Finally a usable SWIG object from the ctypes call 
print(c.msg)
```

This all compiles and works with:

```
swig3.0 -python -c++ -Wall test.i
g++ -shared -o _test.so test_wrap.cxx fun1.cc -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -std=c++11 -DSWIGRUNTIME=extern
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.  python run.py
```

And gives us:

```
0x7fb6eccf29e0
0x7fb6eccf2640
<Swig Object of type 'Foo *' at 0x7fb6ee436720>
Hello
```

To work around the problem of having `SWIGRUNTIME` defined as `static` you'll need to do one more step. Either use debug symbols or reverse engineer the SWIG binary module you've got but can't modify to find the addresses of the two functions we need that aren't exported relative to an exported symbol. You can then use those to construct ctypes function pointers instead of looking them up by name. Of course it would be easier to buy/find/re-write the SWIG module, or add the missing features to the ctypes interface probably.

(Finally it's worth noting that although it doesn't seem to apply here if SWIG runs with `-builtin` some substantial changes will need to be made for this answer to work).

Comment: I can add more details on the reverse engineering needed for Windows or Linux. There is probably another way of doing this, which would be more hacky, but possible using ctypes itself to layout the SWIG Python object itself directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a very detailed and helpful answer. I've been working on this most of today and got quite close, with a similar concept. I still have a small problem with the swig_type_info, I can't use your suggestions, since I got multiple versions of the library. I opted to reconstruct the swig_type_info and fill it using based on the wrapper class names (somewhat nasty, but seems to work). Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah that's a good way to do it also, but harder than just using the lookup helper functions.